# Authenticating with PHP and LDAP with curl

Tags: php, curl

Is there a way to possibly authenticate a user via LDAP but without using the LDAP module of php? Unfortunately most shared hosts do not seem to have ldap module. I have currently got the following working with the ldap module on my localhost but would like to achieve the same thing with an alternative method like cURL or file_get_contents etc.

```
$ldap_connect = ldap_connect("server.ip", 389);
ldap_set_option($ldap_connect, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 4);  

        $ldap_fqdn_user=$samaccountname. "@" . $ldap_domain; 

        if (!($bind = ldap_bind($ldap_connect, $ldap_fqdn_user, $ldap_password))) { 
            ldap_close($ldap_connect);
            echo "Incorrect Username or Password"; 
        } else {
            ldap_close($ldap_connect);
            echo "Correct username and password";
        }
```

Comment: Generally speaking LDAP is an internal/onsite method of authentication, Shared hosts would have no reason to allow this. Best thing you can do is have an API at your local server, which serves Authentication requests to the LDAP Server internally. Although that in itself is a security risk.

Comment: ofc you can just reimplement the LDAP protocol manually with the socket_ 
 api , but it'll be a lot of work

Comment: You *could* implement the LDAP server protocol purely using PHP but you don't want to do that. Therefore, the sane decision would be NOT to support setups that don't have PHP's LDAP module. There's no need to go head over heels to support every poor setup out there.

Answer (score 2):

fortunately curl has native support for LDAP. i have never used it myself, but i guess the equivalent curl_setopt would be

```
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_LDAP,
        CURLOPT_PORT => 389,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'server.ip',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $ldap_fqdn_user . ':' . $ldap_password 
) );
```

here's a fully working example, checking if the password is correct/wrong with curl,

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
header ( "content-type: text/plain;charset=utf8" );
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_LDAP,
        CURLOPT_PORT => 389,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'ldap.forumsys.com',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com:password' 
) );
if (curl_exec ( $ch )) {
    echo "correct password";
} else {
    echo "maybe wrong password? curl got an error. errno:" . curl_errno ( $ch ) . '. error: ' . curl_error ( $ch );
}
curl_close ( $ch );
```

change the password to `paswordd`, for example, and it'll fail. (line 10)

and thanks to http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ for providing the public test server

Comment: Code you posted is unreadable, you don't even touch upon the subject of different authentication mechanisms for LDAP (SSl, TLS, GSS-API, GSS-API + SASL). The code you posted can only be used if you're in the same network as the LDAP server, who in their right mind would expose port 389 / 636 publicly? What's the point in posting a chunk of some untested code that does something you don't fully understand?

Comment: @Mjh in his example code, he's using port 389, which is for the unencrypted version of LDAP, so yeah, the code he wants to port is using the unencrypted LDAP. if you want to use LDAPS, its usually port 636, and you'd have to use CURLPROTO_LDAPS. also i didn't have access to my IDE at the time, which i use for formatting, thus the formatting issues.. but i do now. `What's the point in posting a chunk of some untested code that does something you don't fully understand?` well, because going by the docs, in theory, that should work.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that you're providing a chunk of code that works only in a specific scenario - that scenario is that the computer DOING a request via cURL **must** be in the same domain / network as LDAP server. The other point I'm trying to make is that you're giving away an answer, something that people will consider as absolute truth when they google it, to something you didn't fully test. You could have expanded it, added the caveats and what not, but you didn't. That brings us to what I asked - what's the point? The point is collecting imaginary reputation. Right?

Comment: @Mjh you're at least partially wrong. i tested the code, and it works fine, and i'm not in the same domain/network as the target server. and yeah, the point is to collect imaginary reputation. also i'm bored af.

Comment: @Mjh see the updated post, now there's a fully working, tested example code, happy?

Comment: Yes, I'm happy that I've to be an asshole to explain to a grown man who deals with code the importance of testing and providing full examples of code. Can't be happier than I am currently mate, it's a wonderful world that I live in. Spend the imaginary currency wisely :)